# Can I force a warning on an assignment to a weak parameter?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings, weak-references, autorelease

I am seeing the condition described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13729603/449161) but with an important caveat. Consider this code:

```
@implementation UIAlertView (Factory)

+ (instancetype)alertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                           message:(NSString *)message
                          delegate:(id)delegate
                 cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
                 otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];
    for (NSString *otherButtonTitle in otherButtonTitles)
    {
        [alertView addButtonWithTitle:otherButtonTitle];
    }
    return alertView;
}

@end
```

If I do this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIAlertView *alertView;

...

self.alertView = [UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"Hi" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[self.alertView show];
```

When I build in debug mode it works -- i.e. the factory method returns an autoreleasing pointer, so `self.alertView` has a value. Once it's shown, it's retained in the view hierarchy. This is not something I *want* to do, though -- this was a mistake and it reared its head as an actual problem when I built for release: the compiler (logically) appears to optimize away the assignment, leaving `self.alertView` equal to `nil`.

Even if I switch the analyzer to run on my release build it is not flagging this use of a weak pointer.

Is there a way to get the compiler / pre-compiler to flag this?

Comment: You should be seeing this warning `Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment`.

Comment: Just managed to reproduce your issue, very strange. I would expect it to be cleaned up. Something about it being a factory method is changing that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ARC does not dealloc when pointer is set to nil (using factory methods)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673523/arc-does-not-dealloc-when-pointer-is-set-to-nil-using-factory-methods)

Comment: @CrimsonChris I agree that is a related question, but does not address how I might get a warning when I write code that does this.

Comment: If the compiler is smart enough to optimize my code away, I'd think there would be a way for it to generate a warning, though perhaps this just doesn't exist yet...

Comment: It addresses why you are NOT getting the warning.

Comment: The compiler is only smart enough to optimize your code away because the method you are using starts with `init`.

Comment: But clearly the compiler is smart enough to optimize my code away, because that's what it does when I compile for release. It seems like the static analyzer could do perform a similar inspection.

Comment: It's not optimizing your code away in release, it's probably doing something like what I have in my answer.

Comment: The compiler has not optimized by making a deliberate choice to release the object earlier. Instead, the optimizations in a release build enable the `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue()` magic that avoids ever putting the object in the autorelease pool. So, the release that ARC was always putting into your code deallocates the object. There's no longer a reference outstanding in the autorelease pool. The compiler can warn when a +1 reference is assigned to a weak property, but yours is a +0 reference. If it were to warn about that, it would have to warn about *all* assignment to weak properties.

Comment: Here is a good article on objc_autoreleaseReturnValue() http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/ So my assignment of *alertView to the factory is optimizing out the autorelease, so I get a simple retain count 1 on my object which then goes out of scope immediately after I assign it and disappears (the weak pointer nils it out).

Comment: That said, I can imagine a world in which the static analyzer could walk the code and see what was going to happen -- presumably any case where the next operation on the stack after assignment would reduce the retain count to zero. If I can read my code and see that problem brewing, I'm guessing an analyzer could. That said, it's at the least non-trivial and does not appear to exist.

Comment: Yes, it's conceivable but it would have to be whole-program analysis. I'm guessing that the category on `UIAlertView` is defined in a separate translation unit from the code that's assigning to the weak property.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to get the behavior you are expecting...

```
@autoreleasepool {
    self.alertView = [UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"my alert view"];
}
[self.alertView show];
```

With ARC you are not guaranteed that your object will cleaned up immediately. The compiler doesn't know if your factory method is adding strong references. It could be.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729603/objective-c-class-method-returned-value-assigned-to-weak-strong-properties?lq=1) goes into more detail.

A static method is not always the same thing as an alloc init. The compiler can't tell the difference between +(id)makeMyObject and +(id)getMyObjectThatAlreadyExistsAndIsManagedBySomebodyElse.

Comment: I don't see a warning, even when I do this. I only get a warning if I assign it to "[[UIAlertView alloc] init]".

Comment: You won't get a warning because `alertViewWithTitle` could be creating strong references behind the scenes. The compiler isn't going to analyze my custom factory method.

Comment: So your answer says "Add this to get the behavior you are expecting", but the behavior I am expecting is a warning, which this does not do. Moreover, it's not a reasonable solution to wrap every assignment in an autorelease pool.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't use an autorelease pool here, this answer is attempting to explain why you CAN'T get the warning you are expecting.